# If else failing

Tags: jquery

I Started learning PHP a few months ago, and even though it's providing my site with functionality, I want to be able to polish it up in terms of how users interact with it. (Required form inputs ETC)

I have a jquery statement that checks to see if the values within this select are anything but none. but it evaluates to true and triggers the error message, which it shouldn't. The same sort of If is used when Im testing one condition and it works fine, it just fails with two.

```
<select id="acc_type" name="acc_type">
    <option selected id="none" value="none">-Select Account Type-</option>
    <option id="writer" value="writer">Content Writer</option>
    <option id="manager" value="manager">Content Manager</option>
</select>
```

And later on down in my code I check it with Jquery.

```
var $select = $( "#basic-details #acc_type option:selected" ).val();
if(($select !== "writer") || ($select !== "manager")){
    required();
    return false;
}
```

I have also tried with `!=` as well but it still goes through and runs the function. I've been alright with Jquery so far and the documentation has taken care of most of my problems, but I'm not sure whats wrong on this occasion.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

now if you look at your logic, if $select is not equal to writer or select is not equal to manager then do xxx; The only time it will skip the function is when $select is equal to writer and equal to manager. But how can one value equal to both writer and manager at the same time? so basically its a if(true) statement

Comment: Badoing! I need an && don't I?

Comment: @ThomasFreeborough yep